# Assigning loaded model to a value in object Three Js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm fairly new to Three.js. I want to load a 3D model into Three.js and keep that loaded model as a value in my object, but when I do it like that I can't use this.instance later in other functions in my object.

````
    constructor(name,chords,scene){
        this.instance;
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setTexturePath(`/assets/${name}/`);
        mtlLoader.setPath(`/assets/${name}/`);
        mtlLoader.load(`${name}.mtl`, (materials) => {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath(`/assets/${name}/`);
            objLoader.load(`${name}.obj`, (object) => {
                this.instance=object;
                
                scene.add(this.instance);
                
            });
    });```
````

Answer (score 1):

First of all: The line `this.instance;` has no effect. Besides, what do you mean with "I can't use this.instance later in other functions". Are you getting a runtime error when you access `instance`?

If you want to be on the safe side, put this in your constructor as first line:

```js
const scope = this;
```

Then use `scope.instance = object` in your `onLoad()` callback.

Comment: I added what you told me to, but still get ```Uncaught TypeError: this.instance is undefined``` error when I want to access this.instance in other functions in my object

Comment: Then please demonstrate the runtime error with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: I pasted my whole project here: https://jsfiddle.net/ha3r2d7f/

Comment: Sorry, but the idea is to share a live example that demonstrates the issue. You have just shared your code (which now throws unrelated runtime errors).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I understand, I get the```Uncaught TypeError: this.instance is undefined``` when I use ```this.instance.position.set(chords[0], chords[1], chords[2]);
    this.instance.rotation.set(chords[3], chords[4], chords[5]);```